# How to map my complex type use AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have some problems with AutoMapper. Can someone explain for me how i should create map?
Don't be afraid a lot of code blocks pls. It's very simple logic i just can't understand how mapper work... thank you for help.
AutoMapperConfig:

```
  private void MappingApiInputSubscription(IMapperConfigurationExpression expression)
    {
        expression.CreateMap<ApiInputSubscription, Subscription>()
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.SearchRequest,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>src.SearchRequest));
    }
```

ApiSearchRequest:

```
 public class ApiSearchRequest
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    public bool PriceRequired { get; set; }

    public int? MinPrice { get; set; }

    public int? MaxPrice { get; set; }

    public int? CurrencyId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PublishDateFrom { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PublishDateTo { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EventDateFrom { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EventDateTo { get; set; }

    public bool PhotoAttached { get; set; }

    public int? OwnerId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<int> Offices { get; set; }
}
```

My ApiInputSubscription model :

```
[Serializable]
public class ApiInputSubscription
{
    public string SubscriptionName { get; set; }
    public ApiSearchRequest SearchRequest { get; set; }
}
```

My Subscription model :

```
 public class Subscription : ISubscription
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    public string SubscriptionName { get; set; }

    public SearchRequest SearchRequest { get; set; }

    public ISubscription WithOwner(IUser user)
    {
        user = user ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user), "subscription owner can't be null!");
        var clone = (Subscription)MemberwiseClone();
        clone.OwnerId = user.Id;
        return clone;
    }
}
```

SearchRequest Class:

```
public class SearchRequest : ISearchRequest
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    public bool PriceRequired { get; set; }

    public int? MinPrice { get; set; }

    public int? MaxPrice { get; set; }

    public int? CurrencyId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PublishDateFrom { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PublishDateTo { get; set; }

    public bool EventDateRequired { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EventDateFrom { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EventDateTo { get; set; }

    public bool PhotoAttached { get; set; }

    public int PostsOnPage { get; set; } = 10;

    public PostStatus Status { get; set; }

    public SortPostsBy SortPostsOrder { get; set; }

    public bool OnlyInappropriate { get; set; }

    public int? OwnerId { get; set; }

    public int Skip { get; set; }

    public ICollection<int> Offices { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error saying "some properties on the destination are not mapped"?

Comment: Yep, I am .All  properties : D

Comment: Text, CategoryId and etc

Comment: You need to create a mapping from `ApiSearchRequest` to `SearchRequest`, and then use `.ForAllOtherMembers(dest => dest.Ignore());` to ignore the other properties.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: @stuartd can you explain how it should looks? I mean.. it is separate method?

Comment: something like this? `.ForMember(
                    dest => dest.SearchRequest,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>Mapper.Map<ApiSearchRequest,SearchRequest>(src.SearchRequest)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell AutoMapper firstly how to map ApiSearchRequest to SearchRequest and secondly to ignore all the other properties:

```
private void MappingApiInputSubscription(IMapperConfigurationExpression expression)
{
    expression.CreateMap<ApiSearchRequest, SearchRequest>()
       // add other properties as required
      .ForMember(dest => dest.PostsOnPage, opt => opt.Ignore());

    expression.CreateMap<ApiInputSubscription, Subscription>()
        .ForMember(
            dest => dest.SearchRequest,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SearchRequest))
        .ForAllOtherMembers(dest => dest.Ignore());
}
```